# Invalid dendrogram input (hierarchical clustering)

Tags: r, plot, bioinformatics, hierarchical-clustering

I want to plot a dendogram after performing hierarchical clustering on `top.ranked.genes` matrix.

```
top.ranked.genes <- top.genes.matrix[ranked.list, ]
# Hierarchical Clustering via Euclidean
dat.dist <- dist(top.ranked.genes, method="euclidean") # calculate distance
dat.clust <- hclust(dat.dist, method="centroid") # calculate clusters    
plot(dat.clust, labels=colnames(top.ranked.genes), xlab="Clustered Samples", ylab="Distance", main="Hierarchical Clustering Dendrogram\nRanked Angiogenesis Classification")
```

> Error in graphics:::plotHclust(n1, merge, height, order(x$order),
> hang,  :    invalid dendrogram input

```
top.ranked.genes <-  dput(top.ranked.genes[1:10, 1:5])
structure(c(278.5, 248.3, 349.9, 376.8, 145.5, 149.2, 113.3, 
            173.9, 171, 298.4, 2336.9, 2630.2, 2230.5, 2306, 2209.9, 1945.7, 
            1955.4, 2075.1, 2121.6, 1789.5, 335, 413.7, 438.5, 385.3, 371, 
            373.7, 517.8, 367.1, 798.8, 524, 1073.2, 1305.3, 1163.6, 1089.3, 
            1798, 1473.7, 1486.1, 2015.1, 1582.9, 2078.3, 215.1, 204.4, 771.8, 
            230.7, 66, 100.2, 112.6, 140.9, 46.4, 148.6), .Dim = c(10L, 5L
            ), .Dimnames = list(c("NB_GSM97800", "NB_GSM97803", "NB_GSM97804", 
                                  "NB_GSM97805", "NB_GSM97807", "NB_GSM97809", "NB_GSM97811", "NB_GSM97812", 
                                  "NB_GSM97816", "NB_GSM97817"), c("243879_at", "212126_at", "219315_s_at", 
                                                                   "201554_x_at", "236462_at")))

    

> dput(top.ranked.genes[1:5, 1:5])
    structure(c(1434.3, 1550.5, 1017.7, 1020.7, 1167.3, 1406.5, 1527.8, 
    1370.7, 1543.8, 2009.2, 475.5, 455.2, 778.6, 527.9, 225.9, 280.3, 
    204.6, 300.4, 225.4, 364.2, 2902.9, 3416.8, 2619.6, 2832.9, 4333.6
    ), .Dim = c(5L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(c("NB_GSM97800", "NB_GSM97803", 
    "NB_GSM97804", "NB_GSM97805", "NB_GSM97807"), c("214722_at", 
    "212511_at", "200616_s_at", "214666_x_at", "208683_at")))
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error using the data set given in your post. I used this code: https://pastebin.com/kNTPDxhR Please, could you test the code on your R machine and see if you get the error msg?

Comment: @MarcoSandri you're right. The sample `dput(top.ranked.genes[1:5,1:5])` did not give an error. But when I change it to `dput(top.ranked.genes[1:10,1:5])`, I'm able to reproduce the error (refer to amended question). The error might be due to dimensions, I guess. What's the solution?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the centroid method does not produce a monotonic increase in the height of the dendrogram so you can get reversals. The basic dendrogram plot function does not handle that well. The solution is to change the clustering method or to convert to a `dendrogram` object:

```
dend <- as.dendrogram(dat.clust)
par(mar=c(6.1, 4.1, 4.1, 2.1))
plot(dend)
```

The `par` function increases the bottom margin so that the labels are not truncated.

[image: Dendrogram]