# Plotting a dendrogram in base R with only two leaves

Tags: r, dendrogram

I have some (legacy) code that plots a dendrogram from an `n` by `n` matrix of distances, using base R (4.1.1).
This works fine for `n>=3`, but fails for `n=2`.

```
numElements <- 2

data <- matrix(1, nrow = numElements, ncol = numElements)
data[1,2] <- 0
data <- (data + t(data))/2

d3 <- as.dist(data)
clust3 <- hclust(d3)
plot(clust3, hang = -1)
```

For `n=2` I get this error:

> Error in graphics:::plotHclust(n1, merge, height, order(x$order), hang,  :
> invalid dendrogram input

I would like a dendrogram with two leaves, which will show the height between just those two leaves.

Unfortunately, `graphics:::plotHclust` calls external C code, so I can't modify that directly. And also unfortunately, I'm trying to run this on a pre-built container on a virtual machine, so I need a base R solution without additional packages (else I'd just use `ggdendro`). I can catch the case of only two samples and run a separate plotting function, that is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic dendrogram plot function can't handle a monotonic increase in the height of the gram, like described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68756402/invalid-dendrogram-input-hierarchical-clustering). So you could use `as.dendrogram` to convert it to a dendrogram object like this:

```r
numElements <- 2

data <- matrix(1, nrow = numElements, ncol = numElements)
data[1,2] <- 0
data <- (data + t(data))/2

d3 <- as.dist(data)
clust3 <- hclust(d3)
plot(as.dendrogram(clust3), hang = -1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>